# Get age for Chinese localization in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, ios14

I have this function that works great for calculating age when a user's locale uses a Gregorian calendar

```
func calcAge(birthday: String) -> Int {
    let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    let birthdayDate = dateFormater.date(from: birthday)
    let calendar: NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: .gregorian)
    let calcAge = calendar.components(.year, from: birthdayDate!, to: project.date!, options: [])
    let age = calcAge.year
    return age!
  }
```

The `birthday` value is just a Date() value stored in Core Data.

Here's the Date -> String func

```
func birthdayAsString() -> String {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy"
            return formatter.string(from: birthday ?? Date())
        }
```

But it's failing for when the locale is Chinese. I've tried adding an `if` statement but it still fails to convert properly. Appreciate any insight!
[image: modified calcAge function]

Comment: Can you provide the 'birthday' String that dateFormater is trying to parse for a Chinese locale?

Comment: Hi @JackCampbell - Thanks for the reply. It looks like in my recent test with the device region set to Chinese (Simplified) the 'birthday' string printed as `2月 4, 2015` -- whereas in English it prints as `Feb 4, 2015`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that your date format matches, I noticed that you use `"MM/dd/yyyy"` but you should be using `"MMM dd, yyyy"` based on your comment with the structure of the inputs (`Feb 4, 2015` and `2月 4, 2015`).

Next you want to add `dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: NSLocale.current.identifier)` to your code to set the **date formatters** interpretation of the string. You also NEED to make sure that when you are testing a Chinese string (or any other locale string) that the current locale returned from `NSLocale.current.identifier` is correct. (Or you can manually set if for testing, I set the locale to `"zh_Hant_HK"` and it works with `"2月 4, 2015"`)

Finally, I removed the calendar and replaced the logic using the variable `timeIntervalSince1970` which returns the number of seconds since 1970 and that date. I then took the difference between the current interval and converted seconds to years.

The code below is functional (just make sure the locale is correct for the string you are testing!)

```
/**
 * @returns number of years since birthday date. returns -1 if there is an error.
 */
func calcAge(birthday: String) -> Int {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: NSLocale.current.identifier)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy"
    let birthdayDate = dateFormatter.date(from: birthday)
    var timeElapsed: TimeInterval = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    guard let timeSinceBirthday = birthdayDate?.timeIntervalSince1970 else {
        return -1
    }
    timeElapsed -= timeSinceBirthday
    timeElapsed /= 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
    return Int(timeElapsed)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the details and example @JackCampbell. This seems to resolve the error that would occur when setting the device region to Chinese. This also seems to get the *current* age whereas I'm trying to get the age the user was on a specific date, namely `project.date` -- how would you modify your calculation to use that instead of comparing the birthday date to the current date? Thank you very much!

Comment: I believe I sorted this last part out. Instead of `var timeElapsed: TimeInterval = Date().timeIntervalSince1970` I used `var timeElapsed: TimeInterval = project.date!.timeIntervalSince1970`

Comment: Yes, your solution ^ look good! (I would suggest that you put in a guard statement for project.date, something like `guard var timeElapsed: TimeInterval = project.date!.timeIntervalSince1970 else { return -1 }` just to catch any issues with the  project.date getting force-unwrapped)